# IE11 CSS :hover missing some mouseout events?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover, mouseout

This is a weird one that is difficult to reproduce...

We have the following CSS/DOM constructs:

```
<style>
    .myCheckboxClass {
        border-radius: 4px; /* plus the -mox/-webkit/-khtml versions */
        margin: 0 20px 0 0;
        padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    }
    .myCheckboxClass:hover {
        background-color: #fe9e19;
    }
</style>

<div class="myCheckboxClass">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="cb1" />
        Checkbox Label Goes Here
    </label>
</div>
```

IE11 will occasionally get stuck with the `background-color: #fe9e19;` on multiple elements, so it is seemingly not registering the `mouseout`!? This tends to happen when the mouse is being moved rapidly between elements

[image: Screenshot]

(hopefully the img is showing, but I'm locked out of imgur form work)

Oddly, it's the top right one that we can get to stick most often, and with the margin setting between it and it's left neighbor it's not like IE should be getting confused due to elements abutting each other.

...Bueller?

Comment: You will need a mouse move function to check if any element has mouse over or not then run a function either way...its the esier way around this

Comment: But it's a :hover pseudo-class, so nothing to remove/modify!? If I remove `myCheckboxClass` then the primary style is lot as well. Maybe if I force a fire of the mouseout?

Comment: I have had the same issue using flash as2 sometimes mouse over and off events dont fire correctly when you have certain situations so i would script something to check it anyways... I found to be the easiest solution in your case use jquery or javascript...btw you dont have to modify the class just add the script separately to the document